# why GWT DevMode serialization is hundred times slower?

Tags: serialization, gwt, gwt-rpc

GWT DevMode serialization with gwt-rpc is 100 times slower than production mode. Is there any idea why it is so slow?..

For example serialization of 1000 pojos lasts 67 ms for production mode , and  8000 ms for devmode..

Answer (score 2):

Because in dev mode every call to JS goes to server/IDE, instead of going to browser JS engine. This is especially slow if you attach to remote application through network.

Comment: Same thing here. Have to serialize about 1000 objects, taking 45ms and used debugger to isolate it to just the serialization taking 45sec. Arrrrrrr. Whole RPC works in 107ms in production mode, including HTTP transit.